# Add 'column' to list of dictionary

Tags: python

I have two list of strings (one is iOS ids, and the other App Name)

I'm trying to assign the app name to the ios id, respectively, when I iterate over a function that scrapes reviews. get_reviews() pulls the data from the app store using the App ID. I think I'm close but quite not there yet.

```
iosid = ['123456', '1324567', etc.]
name = ['Target', 'Facebook', etc.]

 data = []

for j in iosid:
    for i in name:
      reviews = get_reviews(j)
      result = [dict(item, app=i) for item in reviews]
    data.append(result)
```

Example of output:

[{'review_id': '83323473', 'updated': '2022-02-13T19:05:11-07:00', 'title': 'I wish all apps were like this', 'author': 'john_doe', 'author_url': 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/reviews/id3435341', 'version': '2022.5', 'rating': '5', 'review': 'I love the app, super easy to use', 'vote_count': '0', 'page': 1, ***'app': 'Target'***},

{'review_id': '83323473', 'updated': '2022-02-13T19:05:11-07:00', 'title': 'Facebook changed', 'author': 'jim_doe', 'author_url': 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/reviews/id3234341', 'version': '2021.5', 'rating': '2', 'review': 'Super hard to use, don't recommend', 'vote_count': '0', 'page': 1, ***'app': 'Facebook'***}]

Comment: Could you explain what's missing from your output?

Comment: Basically the last key-pair where I assign the name of the app.

Comment: Just be careful that you are doing double for loops, which means that Python will go over all combinations of `isoid` and `name` - like '123456' and 'Target', then '123456' and 'Facebook', then '123456' and 'Twitter', etc. I am not sure if that is the behavior you want. If you just want to match '123456' to 'Target', then '13424567' to 'Facebook', consider using `zip`

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Let me look into the zip function which is the intended behvaior.

Comment: You can use `zip` lilke: `for id, name in zip(isoidList, nameList):`. Onething I am unsure is what would you like to be the key of your dict. This seems like an array of dictionaries, so is each ISOId the key? And what is the type/shape of the `reviews` variable

Comment: The reviews variable is a json object with every app review for the specific app ID. The expected output should be an array of json (or dictionaries) objects with their respective app name. (i.e. [{app review1, Target}, {app review 2, Facebook}, {app review 3, Twitter}]

Comment: I would mark your second comment as the answer if I could!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do like this

```py
data = []
for id, name in zip(id_list, name_list):
  reviews = get_reviews(id) # reviews is a list of dictionaries
  # Add the field `app` with value `name` to each dictionary in `reviews`
  result = [dict(item, app=name) for item in reviews]
  data.append(result)
```

Comment: Almost there but basically the answer. Replaced the second line in the for loop with this: result = [dict(item, app=name) for item in reviews]